# Python: simulate tossing a die until all values have appeared at least once

Tags: python, random

I want to sample from a list until all elements have appeared at least once. We can use tossing a die as an example. A die has six sides: 1 through 6. I keep tossing it until I see all six values at least once, then I stop. Here is my function.

```
import numpy as np

def sample_until_all(all_values):
    sampled_vals = np.empty(0)
    while True:
        cur_val = np.random.choice(all_values, 1)
        sampled_vals = np.append(sampled_vals, cur_val[0])        
        if set(all_values) == set(sampled_vals):
            return(len(sampled_vals))
        
sample_until_all(range(6))
```

`cur_val` is the value from the current toss. I keep all sampled values in `sampled_vals` using `np.append`, and I check if it contains all possible values after each toss using `set(all_values) == set(sampled_vals)`. It works but not efficiently (I believe). Any ideas how to make it faster? Thanks.

I just use this as a toy example. The actual list I need is much larger than just 6 values.

Comment: You could try to create a copy of `all_values` and remove the values as they come. It may be faster to check an array's size than the equality between two arrays.

Comment: Based on @MarcoBalo create a set of all values and remove items that where tossed until the set is empty. Removing from set is faster than from list.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think numpy is really useful here as you generate your values one by one.

What about using a Counter?

```
from collections import Counter
import random

def sample_until_all(all_values):
    all_values = list(all_values)
    c = Counter()
    while len(c)<len(all_values):
        c[random.choice(all_values)] +=1
    return sum(c.values())


sample_until_all(range(6))
```

This code is about 50 times faster for `range(6)`, and the difference is even greater when the range is larger

[image: timing]

Answer (score 1):

The following creates a set `a`, which will be a collection of the unique objects in `all_values`. This set will represent the elements that we have not yet seen. As we randomly choose elements from `all_values`, if it is one we have not seen before, then we remove the corresponding object from the set. We continue doing this until the set `a` is empty.

```
from random import choice

def sample_until_all(all_values):
    a = set(all_values)
    count = 0

    while a:
        r = choice(all_values) 
        print(r)
        count += 1
        if r in a:
            a.remove(r)

    print(f"\nIt took {count} draws.")
    return count
```

**Example session** (calling `sample_until_all(range(6))`)

---

```
1
5
1
3
5
2
4
0

It took 8 draws.
```

**Timings**

---

Obtained with `perfplot.show()` with `setup = lambda n: range(n)` and `n_range = [2**k for k in range(11)]`. I removed the `print` statements from my function before doing the timings.

[image]

Comment: I think `a.remove` will be expensive for large input ranges

Comment: @mozway Remember you gave me this `perfplot` stuff a long way back? :p

Comment: I realized I had misread your answer, I thought you used a **list**, of course with a set, `remove` is O(1). So, in the end all answers are more or less the same ± the imports/loading time ;)

Comment: Yes I could see myself seeing `remove` and assuming it is a list too. Yeah, exactly! At least it appears to be an improvement relative to the baseline. @mozway

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that doesn't rely on building and modifying lists (except initially to get a list from the specified range):

```
import random

def sample_until_all(all_values):
    vlist = list(all_values) # list of values to choose from
    target = sum(vlist) # target sum
    seen = set() # values seen so far
    total = 0 # running total
    while total != target:
        choice = random.choice(vlist)
        if not choice in seen:
            seen.add(choice)
            total += choice

sample_until_all(range(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays work great when they have a definite size, but not so much when that's not the case.

The core part of your program is checking for the existence of elements in `sampled_vals`, and that is a task at which `dict`s excel. Converting an array to a dict in every loop, however, is unnecessarily costly. We can thus simplify your code as such:

```
from random import choice

def new_sample_until_all(all_values):
    sampled_vals = set()
    universe_set = set(all_values)
    n = 0
    while sampled_vals != universe_set:
        cur_val = choice(all_values)
        sampled_vals.add(cur_val)
        n += 1
    return n
```

whose key improvements are

- keeping `sampled_vals` as a set, not as a variable-length numpy array which had to be converted every time.
- using a simple `n` counter to keep track of the amount of times you had to sample from `all_values`.

In a simple test on my machine, I get, with `values = list(range(10**3))`:

```
%timeit sample_until_all(values)
>>> 2.6 s ± 1.22 s
```

```
%timeit new_sample_until_all(values)
>>> 2.37 ms ± 11.8 µs
```

which means the new code is roughly 1000 times faster. Not bad!